# Cakephp - Submit Form using Get with parameters

Tags: forms, cakephp, get, submit

I have a form with one input called datepicker,. Everytime the datepicker changes in value I want the form to automatically submit with the datepicker value in the URL (GET).

```
<?php
            echo $this->Form->create(false, array('formnovalidate' => true, 'controller'=>'MCP', 'action'=>'dayview', 'type'=>'get'));
            echo $this->Form->input('datepicker', array('type' => 'text', 'class' => 'datepicker', 'onChange' => 'this.form.submit()'));
            echo $this->Form->end();
            ?>
```

So basically when my datepicker value changes to 2012-01-01, I want the form to submit to MCP/dayview/2012-01-01

I don't want to it to submit as the following format
MCP/dayview?datepicker=2012-01-01

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

lets say your controller is MCP and action dayview

you will to add this Route into this file : app/Config/rotes.php

```
Router::connect('/dayview/:date', 
                 array('controller' => 'MCP', 'action'=>'dayview'),
                 array('pass'=>array('date')));
```

now if you send any request to here it will open your viiew here